# 'HMODULE LoadLibraryA(LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Elem *' to 'LPCSTR'

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

in the vc++ I have a solution with two projects. project A  has a `dllLoader.h` and `dllLoader.cpp` which loads a `dll` with `LoadLibrary` and I need to call its functions in Project B. So I did Copy and Paste the header and cpp file to Project B.

```
Project A Main.cpp
------------------
#include "../Plugin/DllLoader.h"
#include "../Plugin/Types.h"
int main(){
std::string str("plugin.dll");
bool scuccessfulLoad = LoadDll(str);}
```

and here is the dllLoader in Project A (the mirror/copy in Project B get changed with changes here)

```
bool LoadDll(std::string FileName)
{
    std::wstring wFileName = std::wstring(FileName.begin(), FileName.end());
    HMODULE dllHandle1 = LoadLibrary(wFileName.c_str());
    if (dllHandle1 != NULL)
    { ****   
      return TRUE;
    }
```

Building the project itself does not show any error and get successfully done, but when I build the Solution (which contains other projects) I get the error

> C2664 'HMODULE LoadLibraryA(LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'const _Elem *' to 'LPCSTR'

Comment: Why don't you directly call LoadLibrary("plugin.dll")? You pass a wide string to a function that is asking for a string.

Comment: @ZDF Of course, that would fail for the projects where UNICODE is defined.....

Comment: In this case, the correct call would be LoadLibrary( TEXT("plugin.dll" ) ). Or _T.

Comment: @ZDF I don't think so. This code looks like it is written to target Unicode. Unless you support Win 9x you should not be using TCHAR.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The project settings are different.

Comment: @ZDF  yest it was my bad, did not trace the error correctly. Edited the question

Comment: @ZDF Indeed. Which is what my answer says.

Comment: `std::wstring wFileName = std::wstring(FileName.begin(), FileName.end());` - That's a bug. I don't know, why this 'conversion' keeps popping up, but it doesn't convert anything. It trashes data. Unless the source string is strictly ASCII encoded, this will fail. It will particularly fail, if the source string is UTF-8 encoded. We don't know, what encoding your interface expects, so there is little we can do to provide a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `LoadDll()` function takes a `std::string` as input, converts it (the wrong way <sup>1</sup>) to `std::wstring`, and then passes that to `LoadLibrary()`.  However, `LoadLibrary()` is not a real function, it is a **preprocessor macro** that expands to either `LoadLibraryA()` or `LoadLibraryW()` depending on whether your project is configured to map `TCHAR` to `char` for ANSI or `wchar_t` for UNICODE:

```
WINBASEAPI
__out_opt
HMODULE
WINAPI
LoadLibraryA(
    __in LPCSTR lpLibFileName
    );
WINBASEAPI
__out_opt
HMODULE
WINAPI
LoadLibraryW(
    __in LPCWSTR lpLibFileName
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define LoadLibrary  LoadLibraryW
#else
#define LoadLibrary  LoadLibraryA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

In your situation, the project that is failing to compile is configured for ANSI, thus the compiler error because you are passing a `const wchar_t*` to `LoadLibraryA()` where a `const char*` is expected instead.

The simplest solution is to just get rid of the conversion altogether and call `LoadLibraryA()` directly:

```
bool LoadDll(std::string FileName)
{
    HMODULE dllHandle1 = LoadLibraryA(FileName.c_str());
    ...
}
```

If you still want to convert the `std::string` to `std::wstring` <sup>1</sup>, then you should call `LoadLibraryW()` directly instead:

```
bool LoadDll(std::string FileName)
{
    std::wstring wFileName = ...;
    HMODULE dllHandle1 = LoadLibraryW(wFileName.c_str());
    ...
}
```

This way, your code always matches your data and is not dependent on any particular project configuration.

<sup>1: the *correct* way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring` is to use a proper data conversion method, such as the Win32 `MultiByteToWideChar()` function, C++11's `std::wstring_convert` class, a 3rd party Unicode library, etc.  Passing `std::string` iterators to `std::wstring`'s constructor DOES NOT perform any conversions, it simply expands the `char` values as-is to `wchar_t`, thus any *non-ASCII* `char` values > 0x7F will NOT be converted to Unicode correctly (UTF-16 is Windows's native encoding for `wchar_t` strings). Only the 7-bit ASCII characters (0x00 - 0x7F) are the same values in ASCII, ANSI codepages, Unicode UTF encodings, etc. Higher-valued characters require conversion.</sup>

Comment: That should really read *"any non-ASCII characters"*. The failure mode is not limited to ANSI encoding. It will fail for any non-ASCII UTF-8 encoded code point just as well.

Comment: Thank you, this was the best description and understood the type differences.

Answer (score 2):

You pass a wide string to the function. So the code is clearly intended to be compiled targeting UNICODE, so that the `LoadLibrary` macro expands to `LoadLibraryW`. But the project in which the code fails does not target UNICODE. Hence the macro here expands to `LoadLibraryA`. And hence the compiler error because you are passing a wide string.

The problem therefore is that you have inconsistent compiler settings across different projects. Review the project configuration for the failing project to make sure that consistent conditionals are defined. That is, make sure that the required conditionals (presumably to enable UNICODE) are defined in all of the projects that contain this code.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the project column of errors was gone, I now saw the error comes from the copied version of file. Edited the question

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi did you try `HMODULE dllHandle1 = LoadLibrary(L"plugin.dll");`? Does it work?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I'm quite sure that my answer explains the error. The code is written under the assumption that `LoadLibrary` expands to `LoadLibraryW`, but in the failing project it expands to `LoadLibraryA`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, I tried, in the copied version of loader it says: `const wchat_t*` is incompatible with LPCSTR

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi then try `HMODULE dllHandle1 = LoadLibrary("plugin.dll");` or `HMODULE dllHandle1 = LoadLibraryW(L"plugin.dll");`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Of course it does. That's because `LoadLibrary` is expanding to `LoadLibraryA` in the project that fails, and `L"plugin.dll"` is a wide string. Do you know the difference between `LoadLibraryA` and `LoadLibraryW`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky You don't seem to understand this either. There are multiple projects. Some compiled for UNICODE, some not.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `LoadLibrary("plugin.dll");` works in the copy but in original says: `const cahr*` is incompatible with LPCWSTR, `LoadLibrary(L"plugin.dll");` works in original but in copy says: `const wchat_t*` is incompatible with LPCSTR

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks your answer is targeting the problem, but how should I solve it? Project A uses __stdcall convention, project B uses __cdecl

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Let me try one last time. Rather than you trying stuff at random without understanding, I believe the route to solving this is to gain understanding. Do you know the difference between `LoadLibraryA` and `LoadLibraryW`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well I should say not really :(

Comment: Then you need to make that your next task. Once you understand the difference, and how conditions determine whether `LoadLibrary` expands to `LoadLibraryA` or `LoadLibraryW` then you'll be in a position to solve the problem. Until you do understand this I am convinced that you are just wasting your time.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi when passing a **string literal** to a `TCHAR`-enabled API function (like `LoadLibrary()`), use the `TEXT()` macro so the code compiles in both ANSI and UNICODE: `LoadLibrary(TEXT("plugin.dll"));` or `LPCTSTR FileName = TEXT("plugin.dll"); LoadLibrary(FileName);` When passing **runtime data** instead, skip the `TCHAR`-based function and directly call the appropriate version that matches the character type being used: `char *FileName = ...; LoadLibraryA(FileName);` `wchar_t *FileName = ...; LoadLibraryW(FileName);` (you can use `std::string` and `std::wstring` instead, if desired)